# Events not firing within checkboxes in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have tried everything I can think of to get events to fire when a checkbox changes state but I can't seem to get it working.

**Here is the html**

```ts
<div *ngIf="role?.ACTIVE_FLAG === 'Y'">
   <div class="label"> Active Record </div>
      <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleRoleActive()" checked>
</div>
<div *ngIf="role?.ACTIVE_FLAG === 'N'">
   <div class="label"> Active Record </div>
      <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleRoleActive()">
</div>
```

**Here is toggleRoleActive()**
**Edit:**

```ts
toggleRoleActive(){
    if(this.role_submit.ACTIVE_FLAG === 'Y'){
        this.role_submit.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'N';
    }else {
        this.role_submit.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y';
    }
}
```

One of the challenges I am facing, is the button needs to either be checked or not checked when I get data from the server.  But if they want to deactivate or reactivate the role I would like it to respond to the checkbox.

I have tried using `[(ngModel)]`, `(change)` and much simpler solutions, but the only thing that has triggered any events at all is `[(ngModel)]`, but doing it that way I end up with `true`/`false` instead of `'Y'`/`'N'`.  Also if I use `[(ngModel)]`, the checkbox is always marked checked regardless of what data my server sends.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can handle assignment and change event handler separately:

```ts
<input type="checkbox" 
  [ngModel]="role?.ACTIVE_FLAG === 'Y' ? true : false"        
  (ngModelChange)="toggleRoleActive()" checked>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!  You even made my code more concise!  I'll have to remember (ngModelChange) in the future.

Answer (score 8):

I have been dealing with checkboxes like this

```
<input #myId type="checkbox" (change)="myProp = myId.checked" />
```

The component has a `myProp` property defined

Here is more info + a demo http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/input-controls-in-angular-2.0

Comment: Yeah I tried that before from that site!  It wasn't working for me.  Thanks for the reference again though!

Comment: My silly mistake. I was using <input type="checkbox" (onChange)="...">